# Allow only Copy/Paste Context Menu in System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser Control

Tags: menu, browser, contextmenu

The WebBrowser control has a property called "IsWebBrowserContextMenuEnabled" that disables all ability to right-click on a web page and see a context menu.  This is very close to what I want (I don't want anyone to be able to right-click and print, hit back, hit properties, view source, etc).

The only problem is this also disables the context menu that appears in TextBoxes for copy/paste, etc.

To make this clearer, this is what I don't want:
[image: badcontext]

This is what I do want:
[image: goodcontext]

I would like to disable the main context menu, but allow the one that appears in TextBoxes.  Anyone know how I would do that?  The WebBrowser.Document.ContextMenuShowing event looks promising, but doesn't seem to properly identify the element the user is right-clicking on, either through the HtmlElementEventArgs parameter's "FromElement" and "ToElement" properties, nor is the sender anything but the HtmlDocument element.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you considered writing your own context menu in javascript? Just listen to the user right clicking on the body, then show your menu with copy and paste commands (hint: element.style.display = "block|none"). To copy, execute the following code:

```
   CopiedTxt = document.selection.createRange();
   CopiedTxt.execCommand("Copy");
```

And to paste:

```
   CopiedTxt = document.selection.createRange();
   CopiedTxt.execCommand("Paste");
```

Source:

http://www.geekpedia.com/tutorial126_Clipboard-cut-copy-and-paste-with-JavaScript.html

NOTE: This only works in IE (which is fine for your application).

I know its not bulletproof by any means, but here is a code sample that should get you started:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type = "text/javascript">
            var lastForm = null;
            window.onload = function(){

                var menu = document.getElementById("ContextMenu");
                var cpy = document.getElementById("CopyBtn");
                var pst = document.getElementById("PasteBtn");

                document.body.onmouseup = function(){
                    if (event.button == 2)
                    {
                        menu.style.left = event.clientX + "px";
                        menu.style.top = event.clientY + "px";
                        menu.style.display = "block";

                        return true;
                    }

                    menu.style.display = "none";
                };

                cpy.onclick = function(){
                    copy = document.selection.createRange();
                    copy.execCommand("Copy");
                    return false;
                };

                pst.onclick = function(){
                    if (lastForm)
                    {
                        copy = lastForm.createTextRange();
                        copy.execCommand("Paste");
                    }
                    return false;
                };
            };
        </script>
    </head>

    <body oncontextmenu = "return false;">
        <div id = "ContextMenu" style = "display : none; background: #fff; border: 1px solid #aaa; position: absolute;
            width : 75px;">
            <a href = "#" id = "CopyBtn" style = "display: block; color : blue; text-decoration: none;">Copy</a>
            <a href = "#" id = "PasteBtn" style = "display: block; color : blue; text-decoration: none;">Paste</a>
        </div>
        sadgjghdskjghksghkds
        <input type = "text" onfocus = "lastForm = this;" />
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: We had considered a javascript solution and that would certainly work, however the central piece of code for this is in the web browser winforms application we've written, which is used to display many websites.  We own all of the websites, so we could do that, but I was looking for something simple

Answer (score 0):

A quick look at the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser_events.aspx) shows that none of the mouse events (click, button down/up etc) are supported to be used in your program. I'm afraid its either or: Either disable conetxt menus, or allow them.

If you disable them, the user can still copy & paste using keyboard shortcuts (Ctrl-C, Ctrl-V). Maybe that gives you the functionality you need.

Comment: I think you are right.  I think we're going to have to use our own COM Interop wrapper, rather than using the builtin one.  It makes me sad inside, but you are right.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Start:

function cutomizedcontextmenu(e)
{
    var target = window.event ? window.event.srcElement : e ? e.target : null;
    if( navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("msie") != -1 )
    {
        if (target.type != "text" && target.type != "textarea" && target.type != "password") 
        {
            alert(message);
            return false;
        }
    return true;
    }
    else if( navigator.product == "Gecko" )
    {
        alert(message);
        return false;
    }
} 

document.oncontextmenu = cutomizedcontextmenu;
//End:
```

I hope this will help you Anderson Imes

Answer (score -1):

We ended up using a combination of both of the above comments.  Closer to the second, which is why I gave him credit.

There is a way to replace the context menu on both the client-side web code as well as through winforms, which is the approach we took.  I really didn't want to rewrite the context menu, but this seems to have given us the right mix of control.